# How can I cast UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>? to UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!

Tags: ios, unsafemutablepointer

I have an C API I need to interact with in Swift. 
One of the function takes an array of pointers as argument, which is imported by Swift as

```
  `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>! `
```

The corresponding input on the Swift side is AVAudioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData, which is defined as

`UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>?`

I am having trouble casting between the two. 
I tried to make it mutable by doing following:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>(AVAudioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData)
```

And that did not work. The casting between Swift pointer types are very frustrating. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var testPtr : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>! = nil
var testPtr2 : UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>? = nil

testPtr = unsafeBitCast( testPtr2, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!.self)
```

As per excellent @easytarget suggestion since XCode 13.3 use modern syntax instead (not generating a warning):

```
testPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: testPtr2)
```

Comment: As of version 13.3, Xcode is giving a warning/recommendation along the lines of the following:


"'unsafeBitCast' from 'UnsafePointer<T>' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<T>' can be replaced with 'UnsafeMutablePointer' initializer"


Which would result in this simplified example:
`testPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: testPtr2)`